# List of 2-tuples from 2 lists of dictionaries based on value of keys in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists of dictionaries `lx` and `ly`. Elements of `lx` contains a key of interest `key1` and those of `ly` contain `key2`. I want to create a list of 2-tuples (a,b) where `a` is a dictionary from `lx` and `b` is a dictionary from `ly` such  that the `a['key1'] == b['key2']`. Is there a way to do this directly with a list comprehension?

My failed attempt is:

```
out = [(a,b) for a in lx for b in ly and a['key1'] == b['key2']]
```

but I am getting a 'local variable b referenced before assignment' error.

**UPDATE:**

An example input would be:

```
lx = [{'key1': 'a', 'xyz': 1}, 
      {'key1': 'b', 'xyz': 2}, 
      {'key1': 'c', 'xyz': 3}]

ly = [{'key2': 'a', 'abc': '66'}, 
      {'key2': 'c', 'abc': '01'}]
```

output:

```
out = [({'key1': 'a', 'xyz': 1}, {'key2': 'a', 'abc': '66'}), 
       ({'key1': 'c', 'xyz': 3}, {'key2': 'c', 'abc': '01'})]
```

Comment: Do _not_ _ever_ call your variables `list`.

Comment: This is too random.  You are assuming that for some index i that the dictionary from lx has the same key as the dictionary from ly.  If that is always true you don't need any manipulation if not true then you really need to do a bit more

Comment: @DYZ sorry, a bit late over here. Fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `if` before the condition instead of `and`:

```
>>> lx = [{'key1': 'foo'},  {'key1': 'foobar'}]
>>> ly = [{'key2': 'foo'},  {'key2': 'bar'}]
>>> [(a,b) for a in lx for b in ly and a['key1'] == b['key2']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
>>> [(a,b) for a in lx for b in ly if a['key1'] == b['key2']]
[({'key1': 'foo'}, {'key2': 'foo'})]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a really stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: So what happens if they are of unequal length, will this still work?  NExt question, if in your example, lx were reversed would he get any output?  Not trying to push but trying to understand I can't test right now because I have a long process running

Comment: @PyNEwbie My dictionaries are not equal and don't have a single key in common, it works perfectly.

Comment: @PyNEwbie: Yes it will work, no matter the length or order. Of course if order changes the order of result changes too. Check [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for details.